# Notation in Zee's quantum field theory

Tags: notation

I am reading Anthony Zee's Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell(1st edition). On page 123, he does an integration by integrating by parts:

> $$\begin{align}\int&\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\log\left[\frac{\omega^2-\omega^2_k+i\epsilon}{\omega^2-\omega^{\prime2}_k+i\epsilon}\right]\cr
> =&-2\int\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}\omega\left[\frac{\omega}{\omega^2-\omega^{2}_k+i\epsilon}-(\omega_k\to\omega^\prime_k)\right]\cr
> =&-i2\omega_k^2(\frac{1}{-2\omega_k})-(\omega_k\to\omega^\prime_k)\cr 
> =&+i(\omega_k-\omega_k^\prime).\end{align}\tag{II.5.4}$$

I don't know what $-(\omega_k\to\omega^\prime_k)$ is and therefore I don't understand the procedure of the integration. Can someone explain it?

Comment: It means "the same term again but with $\omega_k$ replaced with $\omega_k'$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, notations such as
$$f(x)\pm (x \rightarrow y) $$
or
$$f(x)\pm (x \leftrightarrow y) $$
indicate a replacement rules, i.e. they mean
$$f(x)\pm f(y). $$