# Meaning of Left-Right Arrow in a Fitting Formula

Tags: astrophysics, notation, gravitational-waves, neutron-stars, binary-stars

I initially posted this question on Astronomy Stack Exchange but the site seemed rather inactive so I will try to ask it again on Physics, hopefully it doesn't go against any rules.

I was reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.07728) on the ejecta mass of compact binary mergers and came across this notation in equation (6):

$$\frac{M_\text{dyn}}{10^{-3}M_\odot}=\left(\frac{a}{C_1}+b\frac{M_2^n}{M_1^n}+cC_1\right)M_1+(1\leftrightarrow 2)$$

which is an equation of the dynamical ejecta mass of a binary neutron star merger in terms of the mass and compactness of the two neutron stars with coefficients $a,b,c,d,n$ fitted to numerical simulations. My question is what does the notation $(1 \leftrightarrow 2)$ mean in this context?

The paper being referenced for this equation is https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.03665 and the notation first appeared in equation (1).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/741010/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Very good catch.  Can't recall ever seeing that notation myself.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks! That clears things up.